# Root of .find()-result

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have such a DOM

```
<html>
  you clicked <span>0</span> times

  <div class="button" countSelect=">span">
    you clicked <span>0</span> times.
  </div>
</html>
```

This is my javascript:

```
function increase(i,e){
  var $e = jQuery(e);
  $e.text($e.text() * 1 + 1);
}
function handle(){
  var selectText = $(this).attr('countSelect');
  $(this).find(selectText).each(increase);
}
$(function(){
  $('.button').click(handle);
});
```

What do i need as `countSelect`-Attribute-value to select the first span without change the javascript?

What i have done before?

1. I tried to use `*:root > span`.
2. I tried to use `*:parent:parent > span`.

Both resolve to a length of `0`.

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/08zm3vLu/)

*BTW: Its ok to me to have extra plugins or extra librarys.*

Comment: .find can only be used to find descendants of the selected element. Therefore, given your code, there is no selector that you could place into that attribute that would find the first span.

Comment: And using a extra plugin?

Comment: You don't need another plugin, you just need to use a different starting element (or no starting element)

Comment: @KevinB as i wrote, i can only change the attribute or add more javascript, not change the existing javascript.

Comment: *"not change the existing javascript"* That doesn't make sense. Adding more javascript would be changing the existing javascript. Please clarify.

Comment: @KevinB how would add new javascript change existing javascript?

Comment: Just adding another javascript file to your page will not fix the problem at hand unless said javascript file makes some very serious changes to the jQuery core .find method, which can have wide-spread side effects on the rest of the code that uses jquery.

Comment: A solution to this certainly isn't impossible, but any solution to this that doesn't include changing the existing code will be a poor solution.

Comment: @KevinB So you vote down the question instead of vote down poor answers?

Comment: The answer to this question is simply: "You can't select elements that aren't descendants of the selected elements using `.find`." which you could have figured out by visiting the documentation. The "extra plugins or libraries" part of the question is off topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok we have a good question and a good answer. I will accept this as a answer if noone have a better idea.

Comment: What *I think* you want to do *is* possible, but you would need to be able to change one line of the existing code. Are you able to do that?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I dont need to change on line of the existing code. See the accepted answer.

Comment: @KevinB Please comment the accepted answer how its poor.

Comment: Having done similar things in the past, your answer is a really *really* bad idea. If it works for you, however: good luck :) Sometimes extreme hacks *are* necessary ;) My first version of `findAndThis` did the same thing (until I learnt how bad that was)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Why should this be a bad idea? Please comment to the Answer, not the question.

Comment: You are introducing new code that is hit by every plugin, whether they want it or not. That means everything runs slower for starters, but the potential to break systems is exponential. I did the same thing and was strongly advised not to hack the internals of  jQuery unless absolutely necessary (which it may be if you cannot change the source).

Comment: P.S. When you say you cannot change the source, don't forget the scripts may be modifiable from external code. Functions are just variables after all so you may be able to replace the content of their code with better code.

Comment: If speed is the only problem, i can tune the extension a little. Anyway the documentation of the function still matches, so if there is a problem, its a bug inside of every other plugin. Isnt it?

Comment: As long as the plugins respects the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle  i dont see any Problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works without changing existing HTML or JavaScript:

```js
    function increase(i,e){
      var $e = jQuery(e);
      $e.text($e.text() * 1 + 1);
    }
    function handle(){
      var selectText = $(this).attr('countSelect');
      var $k = $(this).find(selectText);
      console.debug($k);
        $k.each(increase);
    }

    $(function(){
      $('.button').click(handle);
    });
    if (!jQuery.fn.findOrig){
      jQuery.fn.findOrig = jQuery.fn.find;
      jQuery.fn.find = function(selector){
        if (selector[0]==='p' && selector.indexOf('parent') === 0) {
            return this.parent().find(selector.slice(6));
        }
        if (selector[0]===':' && selector.indexOf(':root') === 0) {
            return jQuery(document.body).findOrig(selector.slice(5));
        }
        return this.findOrig(selector);
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


you clicked <span>0</span> times
      
<button class="button" countSelect=">span">
  you clicked <span>0</span> times.
</button>

<button class="button" countSelect=":root > span">
  you clicked <span>0</span> times.
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This relates to another problem I had, so hopefully this will help you. So long as you can change one line of your jQuery code you can support up and down DOM selectors. While it is possible to replace `find` with this code, that is not recommend (not even a little) :)

I created a tiny jQuery extension method called `findThis`, which allows you to use a `:this` pseudo selector. At run time it puts a temp ID on the "current" element and replaces `:this` with that id in the selector. It then applies the selector to `document`. This allows cool selectors like "`div:has(:this)`" effectively allowing you to search both up and down the DOM.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/08zm3vLu/2/

You need to change your HTML to:

```
<button class="button" countSelect=":this > span">you clicked <span>0</span> times.</button>
<button class="button" countSelect="span:first()">you clicked <span>0</span> times.</button>
<button class="button" countSelect="span:first()">you clicked <span>0</span> times.</button>
```

And one line of your code to:

```
$(this).findThis(selectText).each(increase);
```

Comment: Your solution works good, unfortunately i can not change the javascript. But you gave me a good approach: override the `find`-method. This should work as long as jquery do not change their plugin-infrastruture of `jQuery.fn`. I think they shot themself in their leg if they change a official plugin infrastructure of `jQuery.fn`. How do you think about it?